# Resigning applet after packing

Tags: debugging, jar, applet, code-signing, pack

This is the scenario: We have created an JAVA applet, it includes, other than our own code, classes from a couple of unpacked 3rd party JAR:s. We sign the applet, and it runs fine on the clients. We're now trying to make the applet smaller since many of our clients is on network with poor bandwith. So [pack200](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/pack200.html) packing is what i'm looking at.

The problem:

The steps we do for packing with pack200 is basically

1. repack (using pack200 util) our applet JAR to normalize
2. resign our applet JAR using our certs
3. pack the applet JAR with pack200 util

Simple enough and no errors received during this process. However, on the client when they receive this new packed applet they get a SHA1 digest error on classes included from the 3rd party JAR.

The 3rd party JAR is NOT bundled with our own JAR, it's unpacked and the classes are copied into the applet, a single JAR.

This process works on another applet, which includes classes from external JAR:s, so I think i got the process right. I suspect it's something to do with the 3rd party JAR already being signed, but since we can sign our applet and run it in the first place i don't really understand it.

Is there something i've missed? I admit i'm by far no expert on signing, so there could be some obvious thing preventing things to work as i want.

Answer (score 0):

> Found a solution. The link above to pack200 contains a bugreport, which i thought was obsolete since it's flagged fixed. However using the second work around suggested seems to do the trick.